# The action failed to generate or locate a binary. See logs for details

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmepm.png)

Why I cannot run my IBM Cloud Function?
Whenever I invoke my IBM Cloud Function, I get this error "The action failed to generate or locate a binary. See logs for details."

Comment: Include the code for your function, how you invoke it, the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Log, it seems like an indentation issue.
Please try to align the indentation. I experienced the same and resolved it by fixing indentation.

**Issue:**

```
def say_hello():
print("Hello")
```

**Corrected:**

```
def say_hello():
    print("Hello")
```